# Get intent from Android onNewIntent on later timing

Tags: android, android-intent, onnewintent

Is it possible to retrieve the Intent which came in onNewIntent on a later timing?

For example, lets assume that I have a LiveData Observer in my Activity or Fragment, and when onChange is called I want to check if there was a new Intent earlier, with some content in it which is different then the original Intent that launched the Activity?

I don't want to keep a class member variable which holds the new Intent..

Does such thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to keep a class member variable which holds the new Intent.

You do not have much of a choice.

> Is it possible to retrieve the Intent which came in onNewIntent on a later timing?

Only if you override `onNewIntent()` and store the `Intent` that you get somewhere.

> when onChange is called I want to check if there was a new Intent earlier, with some content in it which is different then the original Intent that launched the Activity?

For this, you could override `onNewIntent()`, compare the content with that from the original `Intent` (`getIntent()`), store the results of that comparison in a class field, and then reference that class field in `onChange`.